# Making a Matrix singular

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, inequality, optimization, determinant

During my research I came across the following problem. Intuitively this should be an easy one. However, the simplest version of it looks like this:

> Let $C \geq \frac{1}{2}$ be some fixed universal constant and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given such that
>
> $$C \varepsilon > ac - bd > 0, \quad \text{where} \quad 0 < a,b,c,d \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus we are concerned with a non-singular $2 \times 2$ matrix with small positive entries and a small determinant. Now I want to perturb the numbers $a,b,c,d$ as small as possible such that we have zero determinant.

> More precisely: I want
>
> $$(a + x)(c + y) - (b + z)(d + w) = 0, \quad \text{where} \quad |x|+|y|+|z|+|w| \leq \varepsilon.$$
> Additionally I want the new matrix to be still positive: $(a + x),(c + y),(b + z),(d + w) > 0 $.

Moreover I should emphasize that I'm mostly concerned with showing the existance of such $x,y,z,w$ for a given $\varepsilon$ than really computing them or finding explicit minimal ones.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is your criterion for "perturb the numbers $a,b,c,d$ *as small as possible*"? Perhaps the sum of the squares of the differences $x,y,z,w$?

Comment: I want to add/subtract small numbers ($x,y,z,w$) to $a,b,c,d$ which in total are $\leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: Your problem is potentially slightly more complicated than applying the singular value decomposition. Do you require that the new perturbed matrix is also positive. Must the perturbation itself be a positive matrix?

Comment: @CarlChristian, yes the new perturbed matrix should also be positive (see edit). One may also emphasize that the fact that $x + y + z + w \leq \varepsilon$ is crucial for my considerations.

Comment: You should turn maybe to linear programming. See the powerful function linprog if you use Matlab. But it will not be pure linear programming because you have a quadratic constraint...

Comment: @M.U. Something is unclear in your conditions: instead of $x+y+z+w \leq \epsilon$, dont you mean $|x|+|y|+|z|+|w| \leq \epsilon$ ? In this case, you should modify it in your post.

Comment: I assumed $x,y,z,w \geq 0$ and put $\pm$. I may should add this. Thanks.

Comment: The problem can now be formulated as a question in constrained optimization. Minimize the square of the new determinant, subject to the constraints that the perturbed matrix must be positive and that the sum of the absolute values of the component wise perturbations must not exceed $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is there maybe a way of applying algebraic geometry? Since the equation I want to solve (for $x,y,z,w$) should be some algebraic surface right? However I am far away of being an expert on this field.

Comment: @CarlChristian I started to look at optimization theory (went through a book) and tried to apply Kuhn-Tucker and so on. However it doesn't seem to simplify or even solve the matter.